# "break;" out of "if" statement?

Tags: c

Can you break out of an if statement or is it going to cause crashes? I'm starting to acquaint myself with C, but this seems controversial. The first image is from a book on C
("Head First C") and the snippet shows code written by Harvard's CS classes staff. What is actually going on and has it something to do with C standards?

> **breaks don't break if statements.**
>
> On January 15, 1990, AT&T's long-distance telephone system crashed, and 60,000 people lost their phone service.  The cause? A developer working on the C code used in the exchanges tried to use a `break` to break out of an `if` statement.  But `break`s don't break out of `if`s. Instead, the program skipped an entire section of code and introduced a bug that interrupted 70 million phone calls over nine hours.

```
for (size = 0; size < HAY_MAX; size++)
{
    // wait for hay until EOF
    printf("\nhaystack[%d] = ", size);
    int straw = GetInt();
    if (straw == INT_MAX)
        break;

    // add hay to stack
    haystack[size] = straw;
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: You can't `break` out of `if` statement until the `if` is inside a loop.

Comment: that is how the language works.. a break is only generally useful if it is conditional, and to be conditional, it pretty much has to be in an if statement, right

Comment: The behaviour of the `break` statement is well specified and, generally, well understood. An inexperienced coder may cause crashes though a lack of understanding in many ways. Misuse of the `break` statement isn't special.

Comment: I upvoted cause I couldn't find a duplicate... Even if is an obvious question I think it is a valid question.

Comment: This does not break out of the `if`, it breaks out of the `while` loop. C does not allow `break` when not inside a `while`, `for`, or `switch`.

Comment: Yes, breaking out of an `if` statement can cause crashes, sometimes very serious ones with potential loss of human life. Be VERY careful.

Comment: Are you being sarcastic there? :)

Comment: Just here to point out that the numbers given in the anecdote would mean that the 60,000 people who lost their service sat in front of their phone for nine hours non-stop and tried every thirty seconds to place a call ... Unless someone tried less often, but then it means someone else tried *more* often. None of which is quite believable, if I may.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`break` interacts solely with the closest enclosing loop or switch, whether it be a `for`, `while` or `do .. while` type. It is frequently referred to as a goto in disguise, as all loops in C can in fact be transformed into a set of conditional gotos:

```
for (A; B; C) D;
// translates to
A;
goto test;
loop: D;
iter: C;
test: if (B) goto loop;
end:

while (B) D;          // Simply doesn't have A or C
do { D; } while (B);  // Omits initial goto test
continue;             // goto iter;
break;                // goto end;
```

The difference is, `continue` and `break` interact with virtual labels automatically placed by the compiler. This is similar to what `return` does as you know it will always jump ahead in the program flow. Switches are slightly more complicated, generating arrays of labels and computed gotos, but the way break works with them is similar.

The programming error the notice refers to is misunderstanding `break` as interacting with an enclosing block rather than an enclosing loop. Consider:

```
for (A; B; C) {
   D;
   if (E) {
       F;
       if (G) break;   // Incorrectly assumed to break if(E), breaks for()
       H;
   }
   I;
}
J;
```

Someone thought, given such a piece of code, that `G` would cause a jump to `I`, but it jumps to `J`. The intended function would use `if (!G) H;` instead.

Comment: Your answer seems great. Could you clarify "for (A; B; C) D;
// translates to" in which way specifically? Is it assembly or pseudocode you wrote? Seems pseudocode. I'm pretty sure I understand it and I agree with it thought, I'm just asking because I'm very interested.

Comment: It's actually not pseudocode aside from the capital letters for some arbitrary expressions or statements; that's how labels and `goto` are written in C. The compiler essentially does these substitutions except that it will pick unique names for the labels belonging to each loop or switch. `default:` and `case X:` are similarly special labels, addressable by `switch` but not `goto`.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the conventional use of the `break` statement. If the `break` statement wasn't nested in an `if` block the `for` loop could only ever execute one time.

MSDN lists this as their [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx) for the `break` statement.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned that, *break-statement* works **only** with *switches* and *loops*. Here is another way to achieve what is being asked. I am reproducing 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/257421/1188057 as nobody else mentioned it. It's just a trick involving the do-while loop.

```
do {
  // do something
  if (error) {
    break;
  }
  // do something else
  if (error) {
    break;
  }
  // etc..
} while (0);
```

Though I would prefer the use of *goto-statement*.

Comment: Like Duff's device, it's a bit questionable whether this is elegant or horrid. The `do { } while (0)` combination is also often used to make macros resemble function calls, such that adding a `;` after them doesn't create an extra null statement.

Comment: I would recommend using this when handling roots of a function, since you dont really know how many times you would need to loop a function to be close to 0 and encounter the root, and this loop can guarantee an optimal loop time to find the nearest 0.000... approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a little bit fuzzy - for example, it can be interpreted as a question about best practices in programming loops with `if` inside. So, I'll try to answer this question with this particular interpretation.

If you have `if` inside a loop, then in most cases you'd like to know how the loop has ended - was it "broken" by the `if` or was it ended "naturally"? So, your sample code can be modified in this way:

```
bool intMaxFound = false;
for (size = 0; size < HAY_MAX; size++)
{
  // wait for hay until EOF
  printf("\nhaystack[%d] = ", size);
  int straw = GetInt();
  if (straw == INT_MAX)
     {intMaxFound = true; break;}

  // add hay to stack
  haystack[size] = straw;
}
if (intMaxFound)
{
  // ... broken
}
else
{
  // ... ended naturally
}
```

The problem with this code is that the `if` statement is buried inside the loop body, and it takes some effort to locate it and understand what it does. A more clear (even *without* the `break` statement) variant will be:

```
bool intMaxFound = false;
for (size = 0; size < HAY_MAX && !intMaxFound; size++)
{
  // wait for hay until EOF
  printf("\nhaystack[%d] = ", size);
  int straw = GetInt();
  if (straw == INT_MAX)
     {intMaxFound = true; continue;}

  // add hay to stack
  haystack[size] = straw;
}
if (intMaxFound)
{
  // ... broken
}
else
{
  // ... ended naturally
}
```

In this case you can clearly see (just looking at the loop "header") that this loop *can* end prematurely. If the loop body is a multi-page text, written by somebody else, then you'd thank its author for saving your time.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to SO - it has just suggested the already answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928168/stupid-mistakes-in-c-break-switch-if-1990-crash-of-telephone-network?rq=1) about crash of the AT&T phone network in 1990. It's about a risky decision of C creators to use a single reserved word `break` to exit from both loops and `switch`.

Anyway this interpretation doesn't follow from the sample code in the original question, so I'm leaving my answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly put the if into a foreach a for, a while or a switch like this

Then break and continue statements will be available

```php
foreach ([1] as $i) if ($condition) { // Breakable if
    //some code
    $a = "b";
    // Le break 
    break;
    // code below will not be executed
}
for ($i=0; $i < 1 ; $i++) if ($condition) { 
    //some code
    $a = "b";
    // Le break 
    break;
    // code below will not be executed
}

switch(0){ case 0: if($condition){

   //some code
   $a = "b";
   // Le break 
   break;
   // code below will not be executed

}}



while(!$a&&$a=1) if ($condition) {

   //some code
   $a = "b";
   // Le break 
   break;
   // code below will not be executed

}
```