# How to breaking out of a loop if a condition is valid in PHP?

Tags: php

I searched up similar questions, but none of those gave me answers I'm looking for.

Here's the script:

```
        <?php foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
            if (isset($_GET['locations']) && $_GET['locations'] == $key) {?>
                <img src="images/<?= $_GET['locations']; ?>" alt="" width=500px height=300>
                <figcaption><?= $image; ?></figcaption>
            <?php }
        } ?>
```

I'm trying to break out of the foreach loop once the images clicked matches the condition of my if statement, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your if case, simply add a `break`. If you need more information about break, you can read the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

```
<?php foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
    if (isset($_GET['locations']) && $_GET['locations'] == $key) {?>
        <img src="images/<?= $_GET['locations']; ?>" alt="" width=500px height=300>
        <figcaption><?= $image; ?></figcaption>
        <?php break; ?>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: Hi Chin, I just read an article that said adding a break inside the if statement is a bad idea.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714287/break-out-of-if-statement

Comment: It's not saying it's bad to have a break inside the if statement. It just says you have to be careful to know what you're "breaking" out of.