# Will a 'break' statement break out multiple if statements?

Tags: c, break

If I have multiple if-statements nested inside each other which are all in a for-loop, will a break statement on the inner-most if-statement break out of the for-loop or just into the next if statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695902/how-to-break-out-of-nested-loops)

Comment: `break` doesn't break out of `if`, it's for loops. It will break out of the `for` loop.

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24714287/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe That (first) question deals with nested loops. In this one, there's only one loop.

Comment: @ThomasJager as you point out `break` doesn't act on `if`s though, so the question doesn't make sense at face value.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: [break statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_break_statement.htm)

Comment: you do need to "break" if statements

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It will break the loop (the inner most loop that the if contains in) no matter how many if statments are nested inside. A `break` breaks from a loop and not from if statement.

Answer (score 4):

`break` is only for loops and `switch` statements. It ignores the `if`s and it will leave the loop, as required.

Comment: Only for loops? , `break;` can also occur inside a `switch(){}`

Comment: True. Edited .aS<DkjdcghaslkjhdgasdjklhaSGDLAJSKHGD

Answer (score 3):

A **break statement** only has an effect on **loops** ( do , for , while ) and switch statements (for breaking out of a case ).

**if** is not a loop in any programming language(not in C++ either). If-else statements are conditional statements where you take some actions if a predefined condition is true or false. There is no loop in if statements. So you can't break **if** statement since it is not a loop or switch statement.

Hope you understand!

Comment: What is your source for the claim that `if` is not a loop in any programming language? Did somebody survey every programming language every created, even by a student in a class exercise? Is there no foreign language in which `if` has some other meaning and was used as a loop keyword? Has no assembly language happened to use `if` as a mnemonic for a branch instruction?